# DLL load failure with Python3 (32bit)+PyInstaller+UPX (32bit) under Windows 10 (64bit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, upx

So I'm generating `exe` with `PyInstaller`, using `UPX` as to make the size of the executable file smaller. However, the executable file generated with `UPX` shows errors like this:

```py
PS [path]\dist> .\api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 115, in <module>
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4892, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10747, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
  File "e:\python\python375-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: 参数错误。[Note: "Incorrect arguments" in Chinese]
[133820] Failed to execute script api
```

However, if I use **`--noupx`**, the generated `exe` **functions completely well**. I believe that `UPX` **corrupt**s some DLL files required by libraries like `pandas`, but I'd still like to compress as many DLL files as possible. How should I find out which DLL files are corrupted so that I can include them in `--upx-exclude` list?

Comment: Try using something like [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out which DLLs it tries to load but can't.

Comment: @SitiSchu Thanks! I hadn't expected there would be tools for this! However it seems too old that it *freezes* the moment I import the executable file, about 63 MB :-O

Comment: Just give it a bit of time, it checks if the DLLs exist so depending on the size of your %PATH% it might take a while. I've used it on multiple larger applications with lots of dependencies.